# Identify datetime overlaps and split based on datetime to create rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is a snippet of a data:

```
  ID    Type    Start               End             
1   sleep   01/01/2020 07:00    01/01/2020 12:00
1   sleep   01/01/2020 12:00    01/01/2020 16:30
1   sleep   01/01/2020 16:30    01/01/2020 20:30
2   sleep   01/04/2019 08:00    01/04/2019 10:30
2   sleep   01/04/2019 08:00    01/04/2019 12:00
2   sleep   01/04/2019 12:00    01/04/2019 14:00
2   sleep   01/04/2019 14:00    01/04/2019 18:00
3   sleep   02/24/2015 14:45    02/25/2015 07:05
3   sleep   02/25/2015 07:05    02/25/2015 14:05
```

I want to apply following rules:

```
ID  Type    Start               End                 Rule            
1   sleep   01/01/2020 07:00    01/01/2020 12:00    ok, no change   
1   sleep   01/01/2020 12:00    01/01/2020 16:30    ok, no change   
1   sleep   01/01/2020 16:30    01/01/2020 20:30    ok, no change   
2   sleep   01/04/2019 08:00    01/04/2019 10:30    Ignore  
2   sleep   01/04/2019 08:00    01/04/2019 12:00    select          
2   sleep   01/04/2019 12:00    01/04/2019 14:00    ok, no change   
2   sleep   01/04/2019 14:00    01/04/2019 18:00    ok, no change   
3   sleep   02/24/2015 14:45    02/25/2015 07:05    split           
3   sleep   02/25/2015 07:05    02/25/2015 14:05    ok, no change
```

The final table should look like this:

```
ID  Type    Start               End             
1   sleep   01/01/2020 07:00    01/01/2020 12:00
1   sleep   01/01/2020 12:00    01/01/2020 16:30
1   sleep   01/01/2020 16:30    01/01/2020 20:30
2   sleep   01/04/2019 08:00    01/04/2019 12:00
2   sleep   01/04/2019 12:00    01/04/2019 14:00
2   sleep   01/04/2019 14:00    01/04/2019 18:00
3   sleep   02/24/2015 14:45    02/25/2015 07:05
3   sleep   02/24/2015 14:45    02/24/2015 23:59
3   sleep   02/24/2015 23:59    02/25/2015 07:05
3   sleep   02/25/2015 07:05    02/25/2015 14:05
```

I have hit a mental roadblock and need help to get to the final table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your sample data:

```sql
WITH 
    tbl (ID, A_TYPE, STARTS, ENDS) AS
        (   SELECT 1, 'sleep', To_Date('2020-01-01 07:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2020-01-01 12:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'sleep', To_Date('2020-01-01 12:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2020-01-01 16:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'sleep', To_Date('2020-01-01 16:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2020-01-01 20:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'sleep', To_Date('2019-01-04 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2019-01-04 10:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'sleep', To_Date('2019-01-04 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2019-01-04 12:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'sleep', To_Date('2019-01-04 12:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2019-01-04 14:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'sleep', To_Date('2019-01-04 14:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2019-01-04 18:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'sleep', To_Date('2015-02-24 14:45:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2015-02-25 07:05:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'sleep', To_Date('2015-02-25 07:05:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2015-02-25 14:05:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual
        ),
```

.... create a cte (grid) with statuses of the rows.....

```sql
  grid AS
    ( Select  ID, A_TYPE, STARTS, ENDS,
              CASE  WHEN TRUNC(STARTS) < TRUNC(ENDS) THEN 'SPLIT'
                    WHEN ENDS > LEAD(STARTS) OVER(Partition By ID Order By STARTS) THEN 'OVERLAP_0'
                    WHEN STARTS < LAG(ENDS) OVER(Partition By ID Order By STARTS) THEN 'OVERLAP_1'
                    WHEN ENDS = LEAD(STARTS) OVER(Partition By ID Order By STARTS) THEN 'OK_0'
                    WHEN STARTS = LAG(ENDS) OVER(Partition By ID Order By STARTS) THEN 'OK_1'
              ELSE 'XXX' END "STATUS"
        From tbl
        Order By ID, STARTS, ENDS
    )
```

... main SQL ...

```sql
    SELECT  ID, A_TYPE, 
            STARTS, To_Char(STARTS, 'hh24:mi:ss') "TIME_START",
            CASE WHEN STATUS = 'SPLIT' THEN TRUNC(STARTS) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND ELSE ENDS END "ENDS", 
            To_Char(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'SPLIT' THEN TRUNC(STARTS) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND ELSE ENDS END, 'hh24:mi:ss') "TIME_END"
    FROM    grid
    WHERE   STATUS != 'OVERLAP_0'
UNION ALL
    SELECT  ID, A_TYPE, 
            CASE WHEN STATUS = 'SPLIT' THEN TRUNC(STARTS + 1) ELSE STARTS END, 
            To_Char(TRUNC(STARTS  + 1), 'hh24:mi:ss'),
            TRUNC(STARTS  + 1), To_Char(ENDS, 'hh24:mi:ss')
    FROM    grid
    WHERE   STATUS = 'SPLIT'
    ORDER BY ID, STARTS
```

... R e s u l t :

```sql
        ID A_TYPE STARTS    TIME_START ENDS      TIME_END
---------- ------ --------- ---------- --------- --------
         1 sleep  01-JAN-20 07:00:00   01-JAN-20 12:00:00 
         1 sleep  01-JAN-20 12:00:00   01-JAN-20 16:30:00 
         1 sleep  01-JAN-20 16:30:00   01-JAN-20 20:30:00 
         2 sleep  04-JAN-19 08:00:00   04-JAN-19 12:00:00 
         2 sleep  04-JAN-19 12:00:00   04-JAN-19 14:00:00 
         2 sleep  04-JAN-19 14:00:00   04-JAN-19 18:00:00 
         3 sleep  24-FEB-15 14:45:00   24-FEB-15 23:59:59 
         3 sleep  25-FEB-15 00:00:00   25-FEB-15 07:05:00 
         3 sleep  25-FEB-15 07:05:00   25-FEB-15 14:05:00
```

NOTE: In case you have start until end for more then two consecutive dates you should adjust the code to cover that. This code will not result as it is expected for such a case.

Comment: Thank you! I adapted your code. Have great weekend! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the overlapping rows using the `LEAD` analytic function and then, to split the date ranges on the day boundaries, you can use a recursive query:

```sql
WITH split_days (id, type, start_dt, day_end, end_dt) AS (
  SELECT id,
         type,
         start_dt,
         LEAST(TRUNC(start_dt) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND, end_dt),
         end_dt
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           LEAD(start_dt)
             OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_dt, end_dt) AS next_start_dt,
           LEAD(end_dt)
             OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_dt, end_dt) AS next_end_dt
    FROM   table_name t
  )
  WHERE next_start_dt IS NULL
  OR    next_end_dt IS NULL
  OR    end_dt <= next_start_dt
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         type,
         day_end + INTERVAL '1' SECOND,
         LEAST(day_end + INTERVAL '1' DAY, end_dt),
         end_dt
  FROM   split_days
  WHERE  day_end < end_dt
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id, start_dt SET order_id
SELECT id,
       type,
       start_dt,
       day_end AS end_dt
FROM   split_days;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Type, Start_dt, End_dt) AS
SELECT 1, 'sleep', DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'sleep', DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '16:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'sleep', DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '16:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '20:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'sleep', DATE '2019-01-04' + INTERVAL '08:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2019-01-04' + INTERVAL '10:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'sleep', DATE '2019-01-04' + INTERVAL '08:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2019-01-04' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'sleep', DATE '2019-01-04' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2019-01-04' + INTERVAL '14:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'sleep', DATE '2019-01-04' + INTERVAL '14:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2019-01-04' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'sleep', DATE '2015-02-24' + INTERVAL '14:45:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2015-02-25' + INTERVAL '07:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'sleep', DATE '2015-02-25' + INTERVAL '07:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2015-02-25' + INTERVAL '14:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | TYPE | START_DT | END_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sleep | 2020-01-01 07:00:00 | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 1 | sleep | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 | 2020-01-01 16:30:00 |
| 1 | sleep | 2020-01-01 16:30:00 | 2020-01-01 20:30:00 |
| 2 | sleep | 2019-01-04 08:00:00 | 2019-01-04 12:00:00 |
| 2 | sleep | 2019-01-04 12:00:00 | 2019-01-04 14:00:00 |
| 2 | sleep | 2019-01-04 14:00:00 | 2019-01-04 18:00:00 |
| 3 | sleep | 2015-02-24 14:45:00 | 2015-02-24 23:59:59 |
| 3 | sleep | 2015-02-25 00:00:00 | 2015-02-25 07:05:00 |
| 3 | sleep | 2015-02-25 07:05:00 | 2015-02-25 14:05:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b5oVzTBG)

Comment: Your solution works too! Thank you and have a great weekend! :)